# Custom cell for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, cells

I am new to coding in Objective C. Originally I was bringing in a string of data into my tableView and I was having a really tough time with spacing out everything row by row. So I just need some guidance as to whether or not I am headed in the right direction. I have decided to make a custom cell with multiple views within it. So if I feed each piece of the data separately into each view, would that do the trick of having each row align with one another? Do I need to have anything else within each view i.e. labels? Also how should I think about this code logically? I'm not sure how to send data to each separate view?

Comment: first download the data from the server, parse the response, save in a  `NSArray` then reload everything to `UITableView`...

Comment: There are dozens of samples using custom UITableViewCells. Study one of them, apply what you learned in your code, finally ask a question.

Comment: Yes, so I am able to do that. Before I took all my fields that I wanted and put it into one array and spaced out my data and then sent it to my tableView. The problem is that I'm having a really tough time aligning everything row by row because it is being spit out as a continuous string if that makes sense? So thats why I'm asking if having multiple views within my table view would help to fix the alignment issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to Obj-C coding, go through this [sample app](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/XMLParse.zip).

This sample code demonstrates getting data from server in xml format, parsing the xml response, and displaying in a table, it also uses custom cell to display parsed data.